# Поиск в базе данных mysql части json строки

Tags: json, выборка, sql

Здравствуйте.

В базе данных в столбце content хранится инфа, закодированная в json. Нужно реализовать поиск по вводу в текстововое поле некоторой инфы (прим. артикул товара) и после этого провести выборку в базе данных на предмет содержания введенной информации. Делал так:

```
SELECT id, content 
  FROM $TABLE 
  WHERE content 
   LIKE '%".str_replace('"', '', json_encode($article))."%'"
```

где `$article` - переменная, содержащая то, что мы ввели в поле. Однако не завелось. Заранее спасибо.